# Can a certain branch of philosophy exist and be discussed independently from other branches? 

Tags: metaphilosophy

To be more clearer with the question let us compare for this instance sociology to philosophy, both being a broad subject. Sociology has many branches including political science, psychology, anthropology, etc., yet political science can be discussed without the participation of anthropology in other words it can exist by itself, since their objectives are compleltely distinct though sharing the same referent, the society. In philosophy most branches has the suffix "philsophy" to it like political philosophy, moral philsophy, relgious philsophy, etc., however they have different goals though sharing the same philosophical method. So is a philosophical branch an independent subject by itself than just being a branch under one subject or in other words can a certain branch of philosophy exist independently from other branches as in sociology?

Comment: What research have you done on this question already?  Is there something you find particularly confusing about the answers you are finding in your research?

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes. Philosophy isn't holistic (or necessarily so). Until recently, philosophy itself wasn't an independent field of study. Remember that physics used to be called "natural philosophy." Newton's *Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica* translates as the "Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy." Philosophy, as an entity, is difficult to nail down: there are philosophy of mathematics and philosophy of science courses at most universities. Yet, what is the difference between an course on electromagnetism and a course on the philosophy of physics (or even the difference between the philosophy of physics and the history of physics)? --Perhaps, the difference is problem solving....

But what the hell is this "philosophy?" Is it so enigmatic that it continually changes its shape? Was it once the "love of wisdom" and something else now? Aristotle thought that wonder paved the way for philosophizing:

For it is owing to their wonder that men both now begin and at first began to philosophize; they wondered originally at the obvious difficulties, then advanced little by little and stated difficulties about the greater matters, e.g. about the phenomena of the moon and those of the sun and of the stars, and about the genesis of the universe. And a man who is puzzled and wonders thinks himself ignorant (whence even the lover of myth is in a sense a lover of Wisdom, for the myth is composed of wonders); therefore since they philosophized order to escape from ignorance, evidently they were pursuing science in order to know, and not for any utilitarian end. And this is confirmed by the facts; for it was when almost all the necessities of life and the things that make for comfort and recreation had been secured, that such knowledge began to be sought. Evidently then we do not seek it for the sake of any other advantage; but as the man is free, we say, who exists for his own sake and not for another's, so we pursue this as the only free science, for it alone exists for its own sake. (From Aristotle's Metaphysics, Book I, trans. Ross)

If the above account still applies to philosophy today, then it would seem that, as a whole, philosophy encompasses quite a bit; and yet, its branches are, or can be, quite separate. Few people today would claim that thermodynamics is a philosophical discipline; but, for example, Maxwell's demon is not an experiment for physics: it's a thought experiment. You see, philosophy isn't like other disciplines (I, for one, don't consider it a subject at all), and in many ways, philosophical dilemmas and questions helped create most, if not all, of the disciplines people study today. But, in my long, and perhaps fittingly rambly and scattered response, you should see that philosophy is not the kind of thing you thought it was.

2) Yes. Many philosophers only concern themselves with one or a few of the so-called branches of philosophy. For example, Wittgenstein was mainly concerned with logic, the philosophy of language, epistemology, and metaphysics; he didn't write about political philosophy or ethics (except for one, short lecture on ethics).

Comment: I don't think that the observation that Wittgenstein concerned himself "mostly with logic, the philosophy of language, epistemology and metaphysics" is an affirmation on the question at hand. First of all that's already an enumeration of branches that might be inseparably connected, and second, I think we can agree on Wittgenstein having studied other fields beforehand. You can not "just start" with philosophy of language, therefore I don't agree with your answer.

Comment: I'll try to make myself clearer. Philosophy is not an entity as quantum physics, biological physics, mechanical engineering, and so on (though, some will argue that they're interconnected as well, and I wouldn't disagree). I got the impression that the question wasn't aimed at an existential explanation but rather a more pragmatic one (i.e. "yet political science can be discussed without the participation of anthropology in other words it can exist by itself"). That is, in the question, the branches of philosophy existed independently if they could be talked about independently. And they can!

Comment: But my response was aimed to trying to show (poorly) that philosophy isn't a subject at all. But your thinking that there are "branches that might be inseparably connected" seems based on the presumption that philosophy is somehow similar to, say, chemical biology. I'd hoped that the quotation from Aristotle could have helped nullify that idea. Again, philosophy has only recently become a discipline: one could argue that all human thought is "philosophical," or that the progress of human thought *is* the history of philosophy.

Comment: There's a story one of my professors once told. He was on a plane; the guy sitting next to him started up a conversation; my professor asked what he did, and the guy claimed the he was a philosopher (because he taught philosophy at a university). My professor smiled and said, "that's funny: there've only been seven philosophers in human history." But, perhaps, you don't find it ridiculous that someone can call himself/herself a "philosopher." Whereas, I see this sort of issue at the heart of Tito's question. Someone doesn't write a book on Kant and become a philosopher.

Comment: And lastly, the idea that you "can not "just start" with philosophy of language" is, perhaps, superficially correct, but practically wrong. I know, for instance, a few people who teach mathematics at the undergraduate and graduate levels, and yet, also teach the philosophy of mathematics at those same levels. You might argue that he/she is not a "philosopher" (and from my above comment, I'd agree), but you can't argue that the philosophy of mathematics is not a philosophical subject; further, it seems to me that political philosophy has very little to say about the philosophy of mathematics.

Comment: And, what is superficial is the presumption that mathematics and political philosophy have an underlying ontological or metaphysical connection. For example, the political concept of "equality" and the mathematical one are divergent. Now, it might be argued that any philosophical position taken with regard to these subjects must have either metaphysical or historical foundations. But I don't see how any of this would make the philosophy of mathematics, political phil., etc. require other branches of philosophy to be studied. *Also, Witt. celebrated the fact he was unversed in many phil works

Comment: @Jon: If Aristotle is correct about wonder, then most people, if not all are philosophers to some degree. This doesn't mean they can articulate it, or add something new. Most do not. Those seven philosophers that you mention, represent a culmination of thought/tradition. They are a vessel. Their way would have been prepared for them. I don't know a great deal about the philosophical tradition, but I do know something about physics, so I'm going to use that as an example. The theory of gravity is commonly seens as ones man obsession, Einstein. But the key idea was already articulated by

Comment: Clifford after the invention of non-euclidean geometry. That force was a ripple in space. The Pythagorean cult who are commonly credited with the idea all is number were a religous cult, and they would have had a political philosophy of sorts enacted in their commune.

Comment: @MoziburUllah. I agree with you. I'm not trying to say that there are not often overlaps between different philosophical subjects; I only contend that it is not necessary, at (the very) least practically, to study the subjects of philosophy as an interconnected whole. It is quite possible to study, say, political philosophy without ontology (and so on). I just want to stress that philosophy is not a thing: it is not theoretical physics. (I might add that the invention non-euclidian geometry was prepared for Lobachevsky, esp. by Gauss, before the *Theory of Parallels.*) What is difficult is

Comment: articulating what we think philosophy is--and I don't mean existentially. The "seven philosophers" idea seems more like a "great men" idea, and I don't think it very credible. But it's funny: few, if any, ideas are invented; most are created through connections. (Of course, one of Einstein's teachers at ETH was Minkowski!) But I thought the seven philosophers idea is interesting, as it suggests that there is something *more* to philosophy than simply wondering about things--I'm inclined to say that the wondering man is not the philosopher. What is difficult, I find, is that there is no

Comment: whole, or system of philosophy. I think that is often the confusion about philosophy: you can major--or read--philosophy, get a graduate degree in philosophy, and still be entire ignorant of so many "philosophical" works. I thought this was at the heart of the Tito's question. You *can* discuss mathematics philosophically without regard to metaphysics. To be clear, the reason I responded to the question in the first place was because it's fascinating what people think philosophy is or what people who study it do.  What do you think it is?

Comment: Philosophy is not a thing, sure. Its boundaries are porous. I guess I was reacting to that statement as it appears to be claiming that distinction for itself only. Is religion a thing? Or literature? In Bryans Magee Biography he describes exactly that problem, some students understood the point of philosophy, others didn't even if they could turn in well-crafted essays. Philosophy is a religion. Of course in the West that is contentious. Much less so in the East. It asks questions, it seeks answers, it combs over tradition. Its a higher learning. It has an esoteric side, it has a mundane

Comment: side. It arises from our instinct to understand the world (I do not mean here the purely physical one), and to give meaning to it, it listens to both the finite and the infinite. Its a tool to power and a tool to sustain. It is both ascetic & loquacious. (Einstein said that even he didn't understand relativity when the mathematicians got hold of it). Philosophy is not theoretical physics, true.

Comment: Well, I would say that certain philosophical inclinations often permeate the pores of our ambitions, ideas, and activities––much like religion. However, I find it difficult to say that philosophy is *a* religion. At most, they seem involved in similar sorts of things; but, I cannot see it as a religion. ––I would add that certain political ideologies also have this similar aspect to them. But what separates philosophy is its abhorrence of dogmatism. Here's a known anecdote: 17th and 18th C Cartesians were mostly combating Aristotelians about proved inaccuracies in Aristotle's writings.

Comment: The Cartesians replied that Aristotle was a very smart man, would be able to see where he was wrong, and thus, agree completely with the Cartesians. Who knows if he would have: the point is that a philosophy *can* become dogmatic. And, when it does, something must change. That's where the difference between philosophy and religion lies. Philosophical "systems" don't seem to do as well for posterity (and that's a good thing).

Answer (score 2):

No, the branches of philosphy can´t exist independently. I would even claim that if we think of another possible world where there is only political philosophy, the other branches would soon turn up as well.

Why is that?

Let us think of our political philosopher, sitting in his garden. In order to do his work, he needs to know that there are other things besides him in general, e.g. other humans (ontology) and how we get to know about them (epistemology), that other humans have a consciousness (philosophy of mind), basic concpets of what is right and what is wrong (ethics) and how to properly speak and form rational arguments (philosophy of language and logic).

Of course one could argue that logic (not as a branche, but as logic itself) infact exists independently insofar as there would be the rules of logic even without humans and other living things. To answer this you would have to do some ontology, though ;)

Which then leads me to the question: Where is the border between science and philosphy (if there is one) and could science exist without philosphy?

One border might be the existence of experiments in science and the lack of it in philosphy.
The latter one can be answered at least historical. Most of our sciences emerged out of philosophy. Still, the same motivation that attracts people to the sciences would motivate them to do philosophy aswell.

Comment: From your argument, I'd be inclined to say that nothing exists independently. In fact, it would appear that Tito couldn't even study or discuss political science without somehow engaging in biology, physics, anthropology, and everything else. How is it that I can write and speak and think in English given my ignorance of Indo-European languages? Or, is this a straw man? You see, it seems that either everything is dependent on everything else; or, we can actually do things without concerning ourselves with everything on the periphery. Perhaps this is ignorance––or, it's just what people do.

Comment: On the one hand, my post was about a little thought-experiment, claiming that the branches of philosphy would arise in a world where the people only got political philosophy. On the other hand, i think I´m arguing more for some kind of hirarchy of branches. To study logic, you don´t need political philosophy nor epistemology. But to study political philosophy, you need logic. Maybe logic is some sort of cheating though, but we can run the argument with political philosophy and epistemology aswell. the former needs the latter, but not vice versa.

Comment: @Jon: You are confusing theoretical knowledge with practical or rather pre-scientific knowledge. Tito didn't study physics, although he had a pre-scientific intuition of the physical world based on experience. Likewise, while certain branches of philosophy and of science can limit themselves to their own subject matter, they cannot contradict the others. For instance, physics cannot contradict metaphysics, but a physicist needn't know metaphysics theoretically. However, some fields are too tightly connected to be separated if one desires a full explanation.

Comment: @danielm. See my answer and comments below for clarification. I was specifically commenting on Lukas's post. But I'm interested in how you think your comment responds to anything I wrote. The context of my comment was that I disagreed with Lukas in that I don't see why certain areas of philosophy cannot be studied independently of the others. And, in fact, they are and can be. For example, some studiers and writers of philosophy consider metaphysics to consist mostly of nonsense and originate in certain misuses of language.